# How to calculate the current rating of different metal part (copper and brass) used inside a switch/socket/plug?

Tags: current-measurement, metal

[image: Metal parts used inside of switch socket]

How to calculate the current ration of different metal parts normally used in household electrical appliance product like switch, socket, plug etc. How do i know that, the parts i have chosen that is suitable for particular current rating.I need to know the below topics

1. Effect of copper or brass metal parts
2. Relation between thickness of metal parts and current rating of those parts

Comment: What is "current ration"? Normally household electrical wiring it is made by copper, and more specifically by solid wire. In addition, all connections are maiden following specific technics http://www.homepower.com/sites/default/files/styles/article_image_main/public/articles/images/1_HP152-CC-ground.jpg?itok=dDqQiEbV

Comment: Better conductor / Thicker conductor = Higher current with lower heating.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You start with the resistance of the current-carrying parts. At what rate is heat produced by a given current flowing through a given distance through a material of a given cross-sectional area and having a given resistivity? How much heat is produced by the resistance of the connection? How does the heat flow through the material at what rate is it dissipated into the surrounding air? At what rate does the air carry the heat away from the product? What is the resulting steady-state temperature of the product? What is the effect does that temperature have on the material? You also must consider that heat is transferred to the insulating material that the current-carrying parts are mounted to. The same analysis must be performed for those parts.

To learn how to do that, you start with the study of physics, chemistry, thermodynamics, and heat-transfer. Then you move on to materials science and perhaps some other specialized fields of study. A generalized course in approaches to engineering problems would also help.